# How to set The DataContext of a TextBlock to class at XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I want to set the `datacontext` of a `TextBlock` at XAML.

Resharper suggested this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="50" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Class1}" />
```

but when I run the application for some reason `TextBlock` has as its datacontext the class that I specified at View's code-behind and displays a wrong text

Views's code-behind

```
    public partial class ViewA : UserControl {
    public ViewA() {
        InitializeComponent();
        VmB vm = new VmB();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

**So i want to display `Class1` `name` property instead of `VmB` `name` property.**

Comment: You a create a property of Class1 in the VmB and then bind the class to textblock

Comment: You don't know how databinding works.  You need to stop and read up on how databinding works.  No, I will not give you a link.  Use a search engine to find an article on msdn about windows presentation foundation data binding.

Answer (score 1):

`d:DataContext` sets the `DataContext` for the *visual designer only*. If you want to bind to your class you need to set your **actual** `DataContext` to an instance of `Class1`. Where you get that instance from and how you set it is up to you.

Comment: No, because the code depends on your architecture. Also, learn the basics of XAML and data binding first and this will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to drop the Design parts from your xaml, so something like this ...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="50" DataContext="{Binding Class1}" />
```